# Stop countdown on waiting events on usb port raspi

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie with this python thing but I'm trying to put a barcode reader to work.
I'm using evdev with a raspi and a 16x2 LCD. My problem is simple but I can not find the solution for it.

Link for evdev:

http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-from-multiple-devices-using-asyncio

Initial code I get from:

[How can I get a String from HID device in Python with evdev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732978/how-can-i-get-a-string-from-hid-device-in-python-with-evdev)

To discard mistakes i want to make a timer countdown. In that countdown the user has the possibility of correct the barcode that he is using. For example if he, by mistake, pass the wrong barcode he has the possibility to correct the reading in the next 10 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import evdev, asyncio, sys, lcd, signal, dadosintervencao, time

scancodes = {
# Scancode: ASCIICode
0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'1', 3: u'2', 4: u'3', 5: u'4', 6: u'5', 7:      u'6', 8: u'7', 9: u'8',
10: u'9', 11: u'0', 12: u'-', 13: u'=', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'q', 17: u'w', 18: u'e', 19: u'r',
20: u't', 21: u'y', 22: u'u', 23: u'i', 24: u'o', 25: u'p', 26: u'[', 27: u']', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
30: u'a', 31: u's', 32: u'd', 33: u'f', 34: u'g', 35: u'h', 36: u'j', 37: u'k', 38: u'l', 39: u';',
40: u'"', 41: u'`', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'\\', 44: u'z', 45: u'x', 46: u'c', 47: u'v', 48: u'b', 49: u'n',
50: u'm', 51: u',', 52: u'.', 53: u'/', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 100: u'RALT'
}

capscodes = {
0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'!', 3: u'@', 4: u'#', 5: u'$', 6: u'%', 7: u'^', 8: u'&', 9: u'*',
10: u'(', 11: u')', 12: u'_', 13: u'+', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'Q', 17: u'W', 18: u'E', 19: u'R',
20: u'T', 21: u'Y', 22: u'U', 23: u'I', 24: u'O', 25: u'P', 26: u'{', 27: u'}', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
30: u'A', 31: u'S', 32: u'D', 33: u'F', 34: u'G', 35: u'H', 36: u'J', 37: u'K', 38: u'L', 39: u':',
40: u'\'', 41: u'~', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'|', 44: u'Z', 45: u'X', 46: u'C', 47: u'V', 48: u'B', 49: u'N',
50: u'M', 51: u'<', 52: u'>', 53: u'?', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 100: u'RALT'
}

def parsedados(msg):
   codigo = (msg.split('None',1))
   dado1 = codigo[0]
   if len(codigo) < 2:
       return False
   else:
       dado2 = codigo[1]
       return dado1, dado2

@asyncio.coroutine
def countdown(segundo):
    start = int(time.time())
    elapsed = 0

    while segundo > 0 and elapsed !=1:
        print(str(barcodereader.async_read()))
        elapsed = segundo - (int(time.time())-start)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0) 
        print (elapsed)

@asyncio.coroutine
def print_events(device):
    caps = Fals
    maquina = False
    x=''

    while True:

        events = yield from device.async_read()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY:
                data = evdev.categorize(event)
                if data.scancode == 42:
                    if data.keystate == 1:
                        caps = True
                    if data.keystate == 0:
                        caps = False
                if data.keystate == 1:  # Down events only
                    if caps:
                       key_lookup = u'{}'.format(capscodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  # Lookup or return UNKNOWN:XX
                else:
                    key_lookup = u'{}'.format(scancodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  # Lookup or return UNKNOWN:XX
                if (data.scancode != 42) and (data.scancode != 28):
                    x += key_lookup  # Print it all out!
                if(data.scancode == 28):
                    codigo = parsedados(x)
                    if codigo == False:
                        dadosintervencao.error_handler()
                        print('Passe OT novamente')
                    elif codigo[0] != 'Estado' and maquina == False:
                        maquina = True
                        dadosintervencao.dadosOT(codigo[0],codigo[1])
                        print ('Maquina ' + codigo[0])
                    elif codigo[0] =='Estado' and maquina == True:
                        maquina = False
                        estado = codigo[1]
                        print('Estado '+ estado)

                        print('Espera 10 seg')

                        # ciclo para esperar 10 segundos antes de enviar dados para a base de dados
                        #Att this point it wait for another barcode

                        yield from countdown(10)

                        dadosintervencao.estado(estado)

                    else:
                        print('Passe OT novamente')
                        maquina = False
                        dadosintervencao.error_handler()

                    x = ''

def iniciar():
    barcodereader = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')

    task1 = asyncio.async(print_events(barcodereader))
    task2 =  asyncio.async(countdown(0))

    yield from task1
    yield from task2


def main():

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    

    asyncio.async(iniciar())
    lcd.limpar()
    print('Start %s' %asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop))


    loop.run_forever()


def signal_term_handler(signal, frame):
    lcd.desligar()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        lcd.desligar()
        pass
        sys.exit("Usada teclas de Crl+C") 
    except:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_term_handler)
```

In the end of the countdown the data is sent to some database (not yet implemented).
The function (in this case I'm trying to use a coroutine) countdown is suppose to run concurrently with the evdev asyncio_read(). So when I pass a new barcode it cancel the countdown and start over again.
I'm in this for a couple of days and did not find any solution.

Comment: Is there a flag from usb port that I can use?

Comment: What if they want to scan 3 different items? Will they have to wait 30s to scan them all?

Comment: This is applied to work orders. They just have to scan one order at a time. At first it was 5 seconds. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I will try with a global variable as a condition in the while loop. Everyone say it is not the best of things.

Comment: I can not make it work with the global. I'm moving on with the other parts of the program.