# How to perform Multithreading in Raspberry Pi 4 for multiple input devices

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get input from a barcode scanner, weighing scale and cameras using raspberry pi 4. I figured i'll use multithreading for each of the inputs. I tested each input code separately and they worked but whenever i try to run a multithreading for all of them (just barcode, weighing scale and html for now) I get this error

I am using this barcode scanner [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08D9B7Z9R)

and this weight scale [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GQPV6C4)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Konstant/py/cartos.py", line 142, in initiateBarcodeReader
    s = readBarcode("/dev/input/event0")
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Konstant/py/cartos.py", line 41, in readBarcode
    dev.grab() # grab provides exclusive access to the device
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/evdev/device.py", line 320, in grab 
    _input.ioctl_EVIOCGRAB(self.fd, 1)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

This is part of my code that shows opening the html page and how I call the multithreading. I'm not sure if including the barcode scanner and weight scale code is necessary since they work separately. [Barcode scanner code is here if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135705/how-get-the-usb-barcode-scanner-input-into-python-in-raspberry-pi-4)

```
import eel
import os 
import json
import requests
import shutil, sys 
import os 
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes  
import threading
import time

    def openUI():
        eel.init("../web")
        eel.start('home.html')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        
        ui_thread = Process(target=openUI, args=('UI opened',))
        p = Process(target=startWeighingScale, args=('weighing started',))
        zp = Process(target=initiateBarcodeReader, args=('Barcode called',))
        
        ui_thread.start()
        zp.start()
```

Is this the best approach to simultaneously get data from these inputs and
how can I fix the error?

Comment: Why have you removed the `import` statements - they help us see which packages you are referring to.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added the packages

Comment: What actual input devices do the barcode/scale use - they aren’t on the same device, are they?

Comment: @barny I've added it the devices. They are separate devices

Comment: In general, you should extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, note that a process and a thread are two different beasts, so that might explain your problems.